# Why aren't all the entries going in the file?

Tags: java, file-io

In the following program, loop is iterating 1000 times, and I am writing all the entries in a file using a FileWriter, but unfortunately programs ends up writing only 510(sometimes 415, sometimes 692, always less then 1000) entries in the file, but loop is iterating 1000 times.

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.*;

public class DemoWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<String> receiverList = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        receiverList.add("abc@gmail.com") ;
        receiverList.add("pqr@ibibo.com") ;
        receiverList.add("xyz@gmail.com") ;

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("a.txt") ;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw) ;

        int size = receiverList.size() ;

        String str ;
        int count = 0 ;
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 1000 ; ++i){
            str = receiverList.get( (int) (Math.random() * size) ) + "\n" ;
            bw.write(++count + ".> " + str) ;
            System.out.print(count + ".> " + str) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this because of file size or something else???

---

Thnx for the quick response to all the nice people here. I have corrected my code (I just forgot to close the stream and now code working perfectly). As all pointed that i need to close the stream, but i am accepting BalusC as he was the first one who replied.

Nice to c u BalusC here. 
Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you should always close the resources to flush everything and free up the resources. Explicitly flushing is not necessary as it's usually implicitly done during closing. Just invoke [Closeable#close()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close%28%29) inside the **finally** block of a try-catch-finally block and you're fine.

Learn more at the [Java IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/).

Comment: You don't want to invoke close() in the finally part of a try-catch block - it throws an exception.

Comment: So? Just catch it and ignore further or do e.printStackTrace() of it for logging purposes. It certainly needs to be done in the finally block because you would otherwise leak resources.

Answer (score 9):

You aren't closing and flushing your writers. If you call the `close()` method on your writers at the end of your code, the buffers will be flushed and the writers closed.

As Hank Gay points out in the comments, the `close()` methods will possibly throw an exception (an `IOException`, I believe). This means you'll have to wrap the calls to close in a `try`/`catch` block. However, I see your `main` method throws `Exception` - this isn't the best practice, but it will prevent you from needing a `try`/`catch` block in this particular instance.

Comment: Also, the call(s) to `close()` should be in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to close the BufferedWriter and FileWriter objects?  That can leave incomplete files hanging around.

Comment: bw.close() should pass close() through.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
```

to the end of the method

Comment: The method names are lowercase and I believe (would need to double check the docs), but calling close also flushes the buffer...

Comment: I'm not sure about it. It's certainly so in C#.

Docs say 
"public void close()throws IOException \\Close the stream."

Comment: This is Java, not C#. It could be dependent on the type of writer, however.

Comment: I understand that "this is java", thx. It's JAVA docs about this specific writer, ok?